# handler command failed after migrating mariadb from 10.5.15 to 10.5.16

Tags: mariadb

I have a HANDLER command which works in MariaDB 10.5.15 but fails on 10.5.16.

```
HANDLER INDEX_NAME READ INDEX_NAME = (....,'......') LIMIT 1;
```

The failure happens in'mysql_store_result'.

is there any change in 10.5.16 causing the failure?

from 10.6.x, works again.

Comment: If something fails, your question should be more verbose and tell the readers what exactly went wrong. Most tools and connectors (which one?)  Usually provide an error message, or in case they crashed a trace.

Comment: I have put all information I can get here at the moment, need some hints to continue the investigation.